# How to add downloadable products in woocommerce through frontend form?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add product which is mp3 files means downloadable products and i want to insert this product through frontend form. so only registered person can upload their downloadable products and available for sell.
form the admin dashboard this is easy to add downloadable products. but from fronend how can i do this.

Comment: Hope this will work for you, https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddyforms-woocommerce-form-elements/

Comment: @GirijeshKumar thanks for reply but i do not want to use any plugin, i have designed custom form for the same.